# Why is the E8 lattice free of rank 8

Tags: number-theory, integer-lattices

Let $n \geq 4$ be an integer divisible by 4. Let $E_0 = \{v \in \mathbb{Z}^n \, :\, \sum_{i =0}^n{v_i} \equiv 0 \pmod{2}\}$. Let $e = (1/2, \dots, 1/2) \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ and let $E = \mathbb{Z}e + E_0$ (in $\mathbb{Q}^n$).

Since $E_0$ has index $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}^n$, the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $E$ is free of rank $n$ and it is easy to check that $E_0$ has index $2$ in $E$. Also $E$ is 
 clearly finitely generated. These three facts alone do not suffice to conclude that $E$ is free of rank $n$ in general, as the example $\mathbb{Z}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ shows.

Is there an easy way to show that $E$ is free of rank $n$? (The example is taken from chapter V in Serre's Course in Arithmetic, by the way). Is there an obvious $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $E$ that one can write down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $n\in\Bbb N$ be such that $n\geq 4$ and $2\mid n$, $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ be the canonical basis of $\Bbb Z^n$.
>   Then $2e_1,e,e_1+e_i$ for $3\leq i\leq n$ is a $\Bbb Z$-basis for $E$.

First note that $u_i=e_1+e_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ is a set of generators for $E_0$.
For if $v\in E_0$ then
\begin{align}
v&=\sum_{i=1}^nv_ie_i\\
&=-\frac 12\left(\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\right)2e_1+\sum_{i=1}^nv_i(e_1+e_i)\\
&=-\frac 12\left(\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\right)u_1+\sum_{i=1}^nv_iu_i
\end{align}
But for even $n$ we have
$$u_2=2e+\frac{n-2}2u_1-\sum_{i=3}^nu_i$$
hence $u_1,e,u_i$ for $3\leq i\leq n$ generates $E$.
This is also a basis for $E$, for if
\begin{align}
0
&=a_1u_1+a_2e+\sum_{i=3}^na_iu_i\\
&=\left(2a_1+\frac{a_2}2+\sum_{i=3}^na_i\right)e_1+\frac{a_2}2e_2+\sum_{i=3}^n\left(\frac{a_2}2+a_i\right)e_i
\end{align}
implies $a_2=0$, hence $a_i=-\frac{a_2}2=0$ for $i\geq 3$ and $a_1=-\frac{a_2}4-\frac 12\sum_{i=3}^na_i=0$.

Comment: Thanks! The requirement that n be divisible by four is indeed not needed for this part. (It is only used in Serre's book to show that the standard inner product on Z^n takes integral values on E)